# script in cron job not generating an sql file

Tags: php, database, cron, database-backups

I have this script in ***afbackupdb.sh***:

```
mysqldump  -u user -ppassword --host IP DBNAME > /var/www/html/af/af_core/af_core_cron/afdb/af.sql
```

When I run this directly in terminal it returns the correct sql file with contents.

When the cron does it it returns the same file with same size but I cant open it. I get the error :

```
System Error.  Code: 123.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

[image: iamge]

Above image shows the first file from running in terminal the rest is from cron jobs which I cant open

UPDATE :

In crontab -e:

```
*/5 *  *  *  *   /var/www/html/af/af_core/af_core_cron/affiles/afbackupdb.sh
```

Running my script directly then running : `head af.sql` gets me

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.37, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: IP    Database: dbname
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.6.37

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

While tail .af.sql gets me:

```
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2017-10-26 10:40:02
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention cron, but your image looks to me be a Windows UI.  I assume you are attempting to open the file via Samba/CIFS?  I suspect the issue is an iteration of permissions, whether in Windows' ACLs or [Unix standard ugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions).  The right-caret (`>`) is the likely pain point.  Without more information, my answer below assumes it's a Unix *root* vs *non-root* user issue.

The right caret redirects output from stdout to a file *owned by the current shell user*.  So, even though you're logging into MySQL with your options of `-u` and `-p`, the shell is still writing the file (not MySQL), and the file is therefore owned by the UID of the user running the shell.

When you log in and manually execute your script, your user/UID is the one creating the files.  When running cron, I suspect the shell user is `root`.  Do you edit the crontab via:

```
$ su -
# crontab -e

$ sudo su -
# crontab -e

$ sudo -s
# crontab -e

$ sudo crontab -e
```

All of those end up editing *root*'s crontab, and the resulting execution (and file ownership) will be by the `root` user.

If this indeed is the issue, either use your user's crontab, or consider running your cronjob as your user:

```
*/5 *  *  *  *   su <username> -c "/var/www/html/af/af_core/af_core_cron/affiles/afbackupdb.sh"
```

Comment: i am using winscp for the interface and using putty for the terminal

Comment: SELinux? Sorry not so pro with linux but server OS is centOS. how can i do `head/tail/view/less`

Comment: how can i do `head/tail/view/less`

Comment: Basic command line utilities in *nix land.  Basically, can you read the file when in Putty / at the command line?  Two examples: `head af.sql`, `tail af.sql`

Comment: Okay, so you can successfully read the first and last few lines of the file.  In short, you have permissions to read `af.sql`.  Did you do the same for the problem files?  I'm also concerned that at least from your image, two of the files appear to have the same name, yet do not have the same icon.  Can you find out the difference?  Lastly, do you need to update WinSCP?  I see a couple of forum posts suggesting to update after that code presents.

Comment: i will check the head and tail of the file from cron as soon as it gets generated will post he result as well.. those two files from bottom are both from cron but i deleted them i will wait for new file

Comment: i have generated an sql now maybe the `su <username> -c` did the job will wait for further files and if it is will accept it as soon as possible.. can you share what it did when i add `su <username> -c`

Comment: As stated in the last sentence, it changes context to `<username>` before running the following script.  The written files should be owned by your user (see output of `ls -l`, or perhaps `ls -lh`), and hopefully therefore readable.